# Barrier in MPI: How to implement barrier to make processes wait for one another

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, barrier

Is there any way to add a barrier in MPI code.

By barrier I mean, I want all the different processors to first finish till a point and then carry on from there. That is a processor must wait for the other processors to finish the code till that region and then only proceed to the remaining part of the code.

For Example,

```
int main()
{
.
.
.
  //I want all my processors to do till this and 
   wait for other processers to complete till this point, 
   and then resume the remaining part
.
.
.

}
```

Is there any way to do this in MPIch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That is a processor must wait for the other processors to finish the
> code till that region and then only proceed to the remaining part of
> the code.

Yes, what you are looking for is the routine [MPI_Barrier](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Barrier.html):

> Blocks until all processes in the communicator have reached this
> routine.

> **Notes**
>
> **Blocks the caller until all processes in the communicator have called
> it; that is, the call returns at any process only after all members of
> the communicator have entered the call.**

To learn more about when to use a MPI_Barrier you can read When do [I need to use MPI_Barrier()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305814/when-do-i-need-to-use-mpi-barrier)